# How to make the number of columns same using 'Union' in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, union

Here is the code:

```sql
SELECT 0 customer_id, 0 store_id, '' first_name, '' last_name,
 '' email, 0 address_id, activebool, create_date, last_update, 0 active, * FROM country 
UNION ALL 
SELECT *, 0 country_id, '' country, last_update FROM customer
```

I don't know how to do that for certain data types like boolean type and date/time type like date and timestamp. I'm new to postgresql. So can anyone tell me what values should I put for the data types I mentioned? Sorry for my english.

Comment: You are going to need to show the schema/definitions for the tables ```country``` and ```customer``.

Comment: Instead of 0 and '' you can use null for all data types.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help.

I Tried those on `psql` they work fine:

For `timestamp`

```sql
SELECT  '-infinity'  AS "test" UNION SELECT '0001-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp;
```

For `boolean`

```sql
SELECT  null  AS "test" UNION SELECT 0::boolean;
SELECT  'true'  AS "test" UNION SELECT 0::boolean;
```